# What kinda frame do i have please help

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]
Medium frame
Affinity stickers on frame metal petals straight handlebars

Comment: It's a "single speed road bike" kind of frame.

Comment: How did you get it, and have you asked the previous owner?

Comment: Its my friends and she dnt known either the brand of the bike frame

Comment: Please help me identify the brand name. Of the frame please

Comment: I’m not so sure it is an Affinity, granted it has Affinity stickers but it doesn’t look as high as quality as it should. Judging by the paint chips it’s been resprayed badly and re-stickers in the wrong places

Answer (score 2):

[Affinity Cycles](https://affinitycycles.com/) is a bike brand based in New York City. Looking through their list of [what bikes they make](https://affinitycycles.com/explore-affinity) it looks like the frame is probably the "Lo Pro" model.

These bikes aren't cheap so it is ... interesting that your friend didn't know anything about it.

Comment: An expensive brand, missing parts, "owner" has no knowledge; Theres always an element of doubt in the provenance of ownership for a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a single speed bike, commonly known as a **fixie**. Affinity cycles makes expensive frames, I'd check to see if the frame came from a reputable and established source.